# check whether eth0 is up while my active connection is ppp0

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ping

I've my eth0connection and I've a ppp0 connection.

keeping alive my ppp0 connection, can I test eth0 connection?

like checking

```
ping <ip> <eth0 connection>
```

Comment: Please clean up this question, then provide a small example of the linux? examples you want to use. (The answer might be adding your device in the command or editing the routing table to send traffic by a specific device... Your question is not clear, you need to spend some time to make it specific)

Comment: actually i have both eth0 and ppp0 connection to my desktop . default route is through is eth0. i lost internet because of some issues but the connection of LAN cable is still there. in this case iam switching to ppp0 as my default gateway to access intrenet . but ppp0 internet balance is costly then that of my router. so while iam working on ppp0's internet ,i want to check whether my eth0 internet is back or not . if it is back ,i need to switch back eth0 as my default gateway.                                           i want to check whether my eth0 is back while i'm working with my ppp0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following (Copying from different question that uses your issue [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30408/how-to-ping-use-specific-network-card))?:

If you look at ping manual `man ping`, you can read:

```
-I interface address
   Set source address to specified interface address. Argument may be numeric IP
   address or name of device.
```

So try, e.g.:

```
ping -I eth0 google.com
```

Comment: i tried that one. it only works for the default gateway.     if my default gateway is ppp0 ,then if i try   ping -I ppp0 8.8.8.8 ,then its working , but if i tried ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8 ,then     PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.100.1 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data. and its not displaying anything till i press ctrl+c . then its showing numbers of packets sent and 100 % loss..